# Memory profiling on Android Kitkat, heap Size on DDMS?

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, heap-memory, android-4.4-kitkat

I have one application written using Xamarin.Android, now I need to find out the RAM usage of that application on a device running 4.4.4(Kitkat).

As the Xamarin Profiler and the Android Studio Profiler both don't support Kitkat I  went using the Android Device Monitor (DDMS), but that gives value of Heap Size. 
I want to know what is the exact meaning of Heap size in this case and how can I get the exact RAM usage of this application on a kitkat device.

Comment: Stack and Heap are both for memory allocations, just different types.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I profiled the app on Android 7 using the Xamarin Profiler, the values differ greatly. Like in Xamarin Profiler it goes upto 260mb (Working set) but in DDMS it's only 160mb (Heap size) at max.